# How to develop Breadcrumbs for a single page Backbone.js based ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, breadcrumbs

Im working on a single page ASP.NET MVC application. We are using Backbone.js + JQuery for client side UI and design. I need to put breadcrumbs for Backbone views(which are similar to pages in a forms based application). How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use backbone. It does not matter if you're using ASP on the server. There are plenty of ways to do it. You can place a property in your views that relates to the breadcrumb and then just use it when you render.

If your urls are easily readable you can just parse the url and use that.

Comment: Can you please give a small code example? Shall I use a global variable that will be appended every time I render a view? Can Backbone Routers also do it? Im new to Backbone.

Comment: No global var. The simplest way is to pass a variable from the router. When you create a view do: new View({breadcrumb: 'Page1 / Page2 / Page 3'});

Then in the view's render do:
var self = this;
$('.breadcrumb').html(self.options.breadcrumb);

assuming that in the template you have a container with a class breadcrumb. This might not be the cleanest solution but it will get you going.